# If $\{x_{n}\}$ is a convergent sequence and $\{y_{n}\}$ is a bounded sequence then what can we say about $\{x_{n}+y_{n}\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{x_{n}\}$ is a convergent sequence and $\{y_{n}\}$ is a bounded sequence then I was thinking about a series of questions.

1) Is $\{x_{n}+y_{n}\}$ convergent?, I thought of the following counterexample, Suppose $x_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $y_{n} = (-1)^n$ then $x_{n}+y_{n} = (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent. Is this correct? also any simpler counter examples than this?

2) Is $x_{n}+y_{n}$ bounded? well if $\{x_{n}\}$ is convergent then $\{x_{n}\}$ is bounded then as $y_{n}$ is also bounded, so $\{x_{n}+y_{n}\}$ is also bounded.

3)Now does $\{x_{n}+y_{n}\}$ have a convergent subsequence, a bounded subsequence? how to show this?. I think of Cauchy sequence and a theorem related to this - "Every Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence" but it would not be necessary that $x_{n}+y_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence and hence would have a Cauchy sequence. So $\{x_{n}+y_{n}\}$ need not have a convergent subsequence necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A simpler example would be $x_n=0$ and $y_n=(-1)^n$.
2. It is correct.
3. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. And every subsequence of a bounded sequence is also bounded.

Comment: Great!! thanks, any simple examples for 3rd one?.

Comment: An example of what? In the third one, examples are not needed, since what is stated there always occurs.

Comment: Even though we have the theorem, I was thinking of looking at an example, as thinking of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ as a bounded sequence led me think that there exists a convergent subsequence say $\{\frac{1}{n^k}\} , k \geq 2$

Comment: *Every* subsequence of the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent.

Comment: Wait, "every bounded sequence has A convergent subsequence. " so how you are so sure about - "EVERY subsequence of the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is convergent" ?

Comment: Because that sequence converges and every subsequence of a convergent sequence also converges.

Comment: Great, great, that explains!!